# Splitting a string within a list into a list of lists and further splitting its elements if special character found

Tags: python, string, split

I've got a list of strings that I split into a list of list on ('/>'), yet I want to split the elements of that list within further depending on IF it has a certain character ('/') in it while maintaining the order that the 'further elements' are split in. So for example

```
lol=['FruitSalad://Fruits/Seasonal/Summer/>June>July>August>Mangoes/Grapes/Guava',
 'FruitSalad://Fruits/Seasonal/Winter/>Nov>Dec>Jan>Banana/Oranges',
 'FruitSalad://Fruits/Seasonal/Summer/>June>July>August>Pineapple']

 l1=[lol[_].split('/>')[-1].split('>') for _ in range(len(lol)) if '/>' in lol[_]]
>>> l1
[['June', 'July', 'August', 'Mangoes/Grapes/Guava'], ['Nov', 'Dec', 'Jan', 'Banana/Oranges'], ['June', 'July', 'August', 'Pineapple']]
```

Instead of the above, I'm trying to get

```
[['June', 'July', 'August', 'Mangoes', 'Grapes', 'Guava'], ['Nov', 'Dec', 'Jan', 'Banana', 'Oranges'], ['June', 'July', 'August', 'Pineapple']]
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! Please let me know if my question doesn't make sense.
Not sure if this matters but this should work on python 2.7 and 3.6. Thank You!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. for each element, split on `/>`
2. Take the final element and replace the slash with `>` and then split again

```
 [l.split("/>",1)[-1].replace("/", ">").split(">") for l in lol]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do the following.

```
lol=['FruitSalad://Fruits/Seasonal/Summer/>June>July>August>Mangoes/Grapes/Guava',
 'FruitSalad://Fruits/Seasonal/Winter/>Nov>Dec>Jan>Banana/Oranges',
 'FruitSalad://Fruits/Seasonal/Summer/>June>July>August>Pineapple']

l1=[lol[_].split('/>')[-1].split('>') for _ in range(len(lol)) if '/>' in lol[_]]
final_l1 = []
for elem in l1:
   final_l1.append([])
   for each in elem:
      final_l1[-1] += each.split('/')

print(print(final_l1))
```

output

```
[['June', 'July', 'August', 'Mangoes', 'Grapes', 'Guava'], ['Nov', 'Dec', 'Jan', 'Banana', 'Oranges'], ['June', 'July', 'August', 'Pineapple']]
```

Answer (score 0):

@Kaz Salvatore, try this:

```
lol=  ['FruitSalad://Fruits/Seasonal/Summer/>June>July>August>Mangoes/Grapes/Guava',
'FruitSalad://Fruits/Seasonal/Winter/>Nov>Dec>Jan>Banana/Oranges',
'FruitSalad://Fruits/Seasonal/Summer/>June>July>August>Pineapple']

[x.replace('://', ' ')
 .replace('/', ' ')
 .replace('/>', ' ')
 .replace('>', ' ')
 .replace('  ', ' ')
 .split() for x in lol]
```

**Output:**

```
[['FruitSalad',
  'Fruits',
  'Seasonal',
  'Summer',
  'June',
  'July',
  'August',
  'Mangoes',
  'Grapes',
  'Guava'],
 ['FruitSalad',
  'Fruits',
  'Seasonal',
  'Winter',
  'Nov',
  'Dec',
  'Jan',
  'Banana',
  'Oranges'],
 ['FruitSalad',
  'Fruits',
  'Seasonal',
  'Summer',
  'June',
  'July',
  'August',
  'Pineapple']]
```

Answer (score 0):

you also can use `Regular expression` :

```
import re 
[re.split(r'/|>',l.split('/>')[-1]) for l in lol if '/>' in l]
```